# Definition of integration along fibers in the vertical direction

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading the defintion of integration along fibers from this wikipedia page. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_along_fibers

In the defintion section, they say lift $w_i$ to $\overline {w_i} $

How is this lift done exactly??

Thank you

Comment: You choose any vector $\tilde w_i$ with $\pi_*(\tilde w_i) = w_i$, and you check that the resulting quantity is independent of the choice (i.e., if $\tilde w_i' = \tilde w_i + \xi$ for some vertical vector $\xi$, then the resulting quantity doesn't change).\

Comment: @Ted shifrin Yes I noticed that already. Thank you a lot Dr. Ted